# System.out.println() and BufferedReader mixing up output in console

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader

I am currently working on a program, that uses a `BufferedReader` to read input, and `System.out.println()` for output.

Here is my code:

```
public void chooseMethod() throws IOException{
    int in = 0;
    while(true){

        System.out.println("What do you want to do? (0 to exit, 1 to read Bank         Account, 2 to write Bank Account, 3 to read Bill, 4 to write Bill): ");

        in = Integer.parseInt(cin.readLine());

        if(in == 0){
            break;
        }else if((in < 0) || (in > 4)){
            System.out.println("Invalid choice.");
        }else if(in == 1){
            showBankAccount();
        }else if(in == 2){
            insertBankAccount();
        }else if(in == 3){
            showBill();
        }else if(in == 4){
            insertBill();
        }

    }

    dbm.close();

}

public void insertBankAccount() throws IOException{
    int bankNr = 0;
    int sortCode = 0;
    int accountNumber = 0;
    int balance = 0;
    int interest = 0;
    String details;
    String name;

    while(true){
        System.out.println("Enter bankNr (0 to exit): ");
        bankNr = Integer.parseInt(cin.readLine());

        if(bankNr == 0){
            break;   

        }else if(bankNr <= maxBankNr){
            System.out.println("Invalid Number: already taken");
            break;
        }

        System.out.println("Enter Account Name: ");
        name = cin.readLine();

        System.out.println("Enter Sort Code: ");
        sortCode = Integer.parseInt(cin.readLine());

        System.out.println("Enter Account Number: ");
        accountNumber = Integer.parseInt(cin.readLine());

        System.out.println("Enter balance: ");
        balance = Integer.parseInt(cin.readLine());

        System.out.println("Enter Interest: ");
        interest = Integer.parseInt(cin.readLine());

        System.out.println("Enter Details: ");
        details = cin.readLine();

        bankAccountDAO.insertBankAccount(bankNr, sortCode, accountNumber, balance, interest, details, name);
        this.maxBankNr = bankAccountDAO.getMaxBankNr();


    }


}
```

Now, say I enter "2" to "write Bank Account," the output is as follows:

run:

```
What do you want to do? (0 to exit, 1 to read Bank Account, 2 to write Bank Account, 3 to read Bill, 4 to write Bill):

Enter bankNr (0 to exit): 

2
```

This "2" in the output should be before "Enter bankNr(0 to exit):"

I have had this problem several times, both with `Scanner` and `BufferedReader`, and have spent a long time googling, but can't seem to find any answers.

Has anybody else had this problem? If so, how did you manage to fix it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In your `insertBankAccount()` method inside while loop change :

```
System.out.println("Enter bankNr (0 to exit): ");
bankNr = Integer.parseInt(cin.readLine());
```

To:

```
bankNr = Integer.parseInt(cin.readLine());
System.out.println("Enter bankNr (0 to exit): ");
```

Comment: Thanks :) this worked. I'm sure this'll save me hours in the future:)

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to accept an input before writing the prompt for it.

Comment: I don't think it makes any sense either, but it worked :S

I wonder why it does this backwards...

Comment: i suspect it may block for the next int.